# How to check if app is running for the first time after installation?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net, win-universal-app

How can I check the widnows phone 8.1 app is running for the first time after downloaded and installed the app on their devices?

My scenario is that, I want to create some tables using sqlite-net after the application is downloaded and running for the first time. and also what are the best practice of creating database/dataTables using sqlit-net which are being used in the app?

I am using windows phone 8.1 universal app.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create tables if they do not yet exist? And instead of checking for the tables, you want to check for something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking if it is the first time running you could set a value in

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
```

And check this on app initialization.

e.g.

```
if(!Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("FirstLaunch")){
    // Create Tables etc

    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["FirstLaunch"] = "Launched";
}
```